# (Android) Customize set of symbols on system hardware keyboard popups?

Tags: android, keyboard, popup, character, hardware

I'm owning Motorola Droid 4 (JellyBean, rooted), which has a hardware qwerty keyboard I'm using intensively
It has two kinds of popup baloons with some special chars:

- pressing SYM key
- long-pressing some other keys (e.g. long-press on 'N' gives me 'Ñ', 'Ń' and 'Ň')

Is there any chance to customize those symbols, e.g. add or remove some of them? (speaking of built-in omap4 system keyboard)

(I suppose, that's a thing far beyond common keyboard remapping)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any chance to customize those symbols, e.g. add or remove some of them?

You can write your own input method editor (a.k.a., soft keyboard).

Or, if this is the stock AOSP input method editor, you can modify it and put it in a ROM mod. Or, you can fork it to create your own IME.

Beyond that, you cannot modify the behavior of somebody else's input method editor.

Comment: Thank you! This is the stock AOSP input method, could you please say, in what kind of files (directory, file name or extensions) should I look for to modify? How can I find the proper file?

Comment: @ThyBzi: Sorry, I have not gone looking for those files in a couple of years.